# How do I Use L'Hopitals rule to find all values of K and M such that $\lim_{x \to 0}\left (K + \dfrac{\cos(mx)}{x^2}\right) = -4$

Tags: calculus

Use L'Hopitals rule to find all values of $K$ and $m$ such that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{K+\cos(mx)}{x^2} = -4
$$

I have no idea how to solve this please help?

Comment: Was it edited correctly, @Inceptio?

Comment: I re-edited it, I think this is what OP meant.

Comment: @BabakS.: I just edited with $Latex$, nothing much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 1) What are the conditions that have to be satisfied so that we can apply L'Hopital? More precisely, we know what the denominator converges to, so what does the numerator have to converge to? Then we know what $\cos(mx)$ converges to, so what is the (unique) possibility for the value of $K$?

2) If you apply L'Hopital twice, you will get an expression for $m$, or rather for $m^2$. What are the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As $$\cos(mx)=1-\frac{m^2x^2}{2} + \frac{m^4x^4}{4!}\mp \dots$$ the limit can only exists when $K=-1$.

Than we have 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{m^2}{2} + \frac{m^4 x^2}{4!} \mp \dots=-\frac{m^2}{2}=-4$$

Comment: How do you conclude limit exists only when $K=-1$? That's supposed to be one can apply the L'Hospital's rule iff $K=-1$

Comment: the nominator must have a zero of order at least 2 else we would need that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ or $\frac{1}{x}$ is bounded at 0

Comment: **IF** $K \neq 0$, the limit is either $-\infty$ or $\infty$? Is that true?

Comment: @Inceptio if $K\neq -1$ the "limit" is either $-\infty$ or $\infty$  yes

Comment: Doesn't it mean it exists? Its tending to something very large or small.!

Comment: nope I said "limit" cause a limit must be a real value as it is a real valued function, as $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are not in $\mathbb{R}$ those can't be a limit

Comment: I had some cracks in the concept.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$K$ must be $-1$ to even apply the rule.  Differentiate to get $\lim \frac{-\sin(mx)m}{2x}= \lim\frac{-1}{2}\frac{\sin(mx)m^2}{mx}$, so $\frac{-m^2}{2} = -4$